# Firefox doesn't reload E-Bay pages unless I clear the cache

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, browser-cache

When I have tabs open watching items on E-bay, I have to manually clear the cache (I leave history, cookies, and logons unchecked) in order for the pages to reload.  If I don't, the page reloads with the same time remaining in the auction when I hit the reload button - even if it's 45 minutes later. If I reload after clearing the cache and there's less than 30 (or so ?) minutes left, the page counts down, and updates the page when the auction is over - so that part is working ok.

Firefox 3.6.8; Windows XP SP2 (PIII laptop won't do SP3)

Answer (score 1):

You can do a CTRL + F5 to force a refresh of the page.

Comment: That seems to work. Thanks.  Is there a setting to only reload pages that have changed?  I thought I saw that somewhere.

Comment: In Firefox you can go to about:config and search for browser.cache.check_doc_frequency.  It should be set to 3, which means Check for a new version when the page is out of date. (Default) .  It might be that eBay isn't sending the correct headers for the file.
Also if that works, please accept it as an answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox goto  Tools->Options->Advanced->Network->Offline Storage->Use upto 50 MB change that to 0 MB

Now none of your pages will be served from cache. This should load your site directly from web rather than using cache.

Comment: I don't want to reload  pages that haven't changed - slow browsing.  I thought I remembered an option to only reload changed pages.